# Godel's proof of Completeness

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

Where could I find a detailed exposition in *English* of Godel's proof (not Henkin's) of Completeness Theorem for first order logic? The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_proof_of_G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) omits certain details that I am not clear about, and Godel's original dissertation is not in English.

Comment: https://global.oup.com/academic/product/collected-works-9780195147209?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: If you are interested in a text book treatment which leads you from the basics to a proof of Gödel's theorem, then I can highly recommend "Mathematical Logic" by Shoenfield which was (is ?) the standard graduate text on the subject of its title.

Comment: @oeiras: The proof of completeness given by Shoenfield is the one due to Henkin, which is not what the questioner wants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to an English translation of the original version contained in the Collected Works referred to by Andrés, there is an English translation of a rewritten version of the paper contained in *From Frege to Gödel* edited by Jean van Heijenoort. The latter is also contained in the Collected Works.